# store batched kafka messages in storm need some example

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-storm

I tried with normal consumer example to retrieve the message.But now my consumer is storm so i need to store batched kafka messages in storm need some example.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the [storm-kafka](https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/external/storm-kafka) spout. You can find several examples on their page. I needed the `KafkaSpout` class in my application, but they seem to also support batches:

```java
Fields fields = new Fields("key", "message");
FixedBatchSpout spout = new FixedBatchSpout(fields, 4,
            new Values("storm", "1"),
            new Values("trident", "1"),
            new Values("needs", "1"),
            new Values("javadoc", "1")
);
spout.setCycle(true);
builder.setSpout("spout", spout, 5);
```

Please narrow down the question if you need more specific examples.